# Yii CDBCriteria Complex Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I have 3 tables:

1. bank
2. bank_details
3. bank_bank_details

Relation between them:

**bank model:**

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'bankBankDetails' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BankBankDetails', 'bank_id'),
        );
}
```

**bank_details model:**

```
public function relations() {
        return array(
            'bankBankDetails' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BankBankDetails', 'bank_details_id'),
        );
    }
```

**bank_bank_details model:**

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'bank' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Bank', 'bank_id'),            
            'bankDetails' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BankDetails', 'bank_details_id'),
        );
    }
```

I want to fetch bank details like bank_name, ifsc etc info in admin view of **bank_details** model.

The normal SQL query I have generated which works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bank b
LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bbd.bank_id = b.bank_id
LEFT JOIN bank_details bd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id
WHERE bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now I just wants to integrate this with Yii CDBCriteria but its not working for me. Please check the code below:

```
public function search() {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;    
//        select b.name
//        from bank b
//        left join bank_bank_details bbd
//        on bbd.bank_id = b.bank_id
//        left join bank_details bd on bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id
//        WHERE bd.bank_details_id = bbd . bank_details_id;

        $criteria->compare('bank_details_id', $this->bank_details_id);
        $criteria->compare('first_holder_name', $this->first_holder_name, true);
        $criteria->compare('nominee1', $this->nominee1, true);
        $criteria->select = 'b.name';
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bbd.bank_id = b.bank_id ';
        $criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN bank_details bd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id';
        $criteria->condition = 'bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id';

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ),
        ));
    }
```

**Error:**
        **Error 500 Found
        CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'b.bank_id' in 'on clause'**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set alias to your table like this:
`$criteria->alias='b';` or use default alias "t" instead of "b"

read more at
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail

Comment: I tried both but its not working: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.bank_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: This error message says that table alias didn't set.
I just tried this code
`$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'b.name';
$criteria->alias = 'b';
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bbd.bank_id = b.bank_id ';
$criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN bank_details bd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id';
$criteria->condition = 'bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id';
...`
and it works.
Do you have sql query, that causes your error, in logs?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public function search() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;    
    $criteria->compare('bank_details_id', $this->bank_details_id);
    $criteria->compare('first_holder_name', $this->first_holder_name, true);
    $criteria->compare('nominee1', $this->nominee1, true);
    $criteria->select = 'bank.name';
    $criteria->with = array(
         'bankBankDetails' => array('joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN'),
         'bankBankDetails.bank' => array('joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN'),
    );
    $criteria->addCondition('t.bank_details_id = bankBankDetails.bank_details_id');

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Main table (which is in FROM) has alias `t` and after `compare` you already having some condition, than you need to add to existing, not rewrite

**UPDATE**

If you do query from model `bank_details` then the main table (in `FROM`) must be `bank_details`. Query will be:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bank_details bd
LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id
LEFT JOIN bank b bbd ON bbd.bank_id = b.bank_id
WHERE bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Like this: `$criteria->select = 'b.name';
        $criteria->alias = 'bank t';
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bbd.bank_id = t.bank_id ';
        $criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN bank_details bd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id';
        $criteria->addCondition('bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id');` right?

Comment: I'm update answer with full solution and with out changing alias of main table to `b` (it doesn't matter). Just remember: main table in ActiveRecord queries always has alias `t`, but you can change it if you want

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but same error :( `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.bank_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Now its showing: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'`

Comment: Ok, and the last try: add `t.` to `name` in `select` (see answer)

Comment: No bro... same issue: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.name' in 'field list'`. I am not getting where I am going wrong. Is there any issue in relation? Because the sql query works perfectly fine.

Comment: I found the problem. If you do it from `bank_details` than in `FROM` must be table `bank_details`. Try new solution

Comment: Yes exactly. Can I use normal query? Will it work on gridview?

Comment: I posted new query, with will be using my solution. I'm not understand full task, but it must work good in gridview.

Comment: This time its showing following error: `Active record "BankDetails" is trying to select an invalid column "bank.name". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.`

Comment: This means that query works fine and model `BankDetails` hasn't property for loading this value. Try change select to `b.name as bank_name` and add property `public $bank_name` to model `BankDetails `. But I don't like all it is. Maybe you think better about relation: you can get bank name by following code: `$bname = $bank_detail_item->bankBankDetails[0]->bank->name`?!

Comment: You means like this: `$criteria->select = 'bank.name as bank_name';
        $criteria->with = array(
            'bankBankDetails' => array('joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN'),
            'bankBankDetails.bank' => array('joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN'),
        );
        $criteria->addCondition('t.bank_details_id = bankBankDetails.bank_details_id');` right?

Comment: Yes, and don't forget about property in model `BankDetails`

Comment: Yes I've added property: `public $bank_name;` but still its showing `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bank.name' in 'field list'`

Comment: try to see on sql query, with formed in `search`. You can do it by placing this code `exit( $this->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($this->getTableSchema(), $this->getDbCriteria())->text );` before `return`. It must show you sql query...

Comment: I think there is error in query its returning only `SELECT * FROM `bank_details` `t``

Comment: I'm sorry, I made mistake, here is the code: `exit( $this->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($this->getTableSchema(), $criteria)->text );`

Comment: ok thanks. Now result is : `SELECT bank.name as bank_name 
FROM `bank_details` `t` 
WHERE t.bank_details_id = bankBankDetails.bank_details_id;`

Comment: Not working joins... I don't know why. Try your variant with join but with this context: `$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN bank_bank_details bbd ON bd.bank_details_id = bbd.bank_details_id'; $criteria->join .= 'LEFT JOIN bank ON bbd.bank_id = bank.bank_id';` instead `$criteria->with(...)`. And remove `$criteria->addCondition(...)` - it using in join condition

Comment: Now weird error came: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'bank'`

Comment: Is it possible to join a table to bank `$criteria->with = array(
         'bankBankDetails' => array('joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN'),'bankBankDetails.bank' => array('joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN'),
         'bankBankDetails.bank.newTable' => array('joinType'=>'LEFT JOIN'),
    );`

Answer (score 0):

here
`$criteria->select = 'b.name';`
You are selecting only bank name and no id is selected

Not sure with the yii format something like

`$criteria->select = 'b.name,b.bank_id';`

or

`$criteria->select = array('b.name,b.bank_id');`

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have select name because I only want to display bank name on admin grid view not the id. Also I tried both the syntax but its not working.

Comment: then you should hide the id from the grid,not from the sql query @Ultimate

Comment: Ok. But the condition is also not working. It showing me same error

Answer (score 0):

As @Evgeniy mentioned, you will need to set the alias using `$criteria->alias = 'b';`

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#alias-detail

You might also want to look into using `CDbCriteria::with` you can use this to select related models.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail

If you use the above, make sure you also use `CDbCriteria::together` correctly.  To select all related models at once, set it to `true`;

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail